# What would an alternative sentence for percentage in writing?

Tags: writing, academia, reference, percentages

What would be an alternative sentence or word for percentage in writing? For example, when referencing to a sentence, if the sentence has 50%, we can use words like half of the total amount or similar.

What would be the alternative word or sentence for 9%?

Comment: Just as you replace 50% with "half", replace a different percentage with its equivalent fraction. 9% is approximately an eleventh, or just under a tenth, or just over a twelfth.

Comment: Could it be relevant using something like less than quarter, or one significant portion?

Comment: 9% is certainly less than a quarter, it may be significant. There's no way anyone here can make that sort of value judgement.

Comment: an eleventh is more relevant though. Thank you @andrew

Comment: I see "pc" used, as in "50 pc", in documentation.  I don't like though.  Best answer so far is Alsop's.

Answer (score 2):

There is only a sentence equivalent for simple fractions, such as quarter, eighth, even twelfth. For something like 9%, there isn't a simple fraction, so the best you could do was write, "nine hundredths" or as Andrew Leach pointed out, if you are happy to approximate, then you could go for, "an eleventh."

Answer (score 0):

It is utterly correct to say "fifty percent" or "fifty per cent" (that is, spelling everything out).

In a technical paper, and in most papers where the exact statistic really matters, you would want to spell it out as above instead of using an expression like "one half," "exactly half," or "fully one half."